# Meteor + Bootstrap - Alert closed.bs.alert does not trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Meteor and Bootstrap, with the `nemo64:bootstrap` package. In `custom.bootstrap.json` I have "alerts" and "alert" on.

I'm trying to capture the [closed.bs.alert](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts) event in a Template events. For some reason, it won't capture.

```
Template.alert.events({
    'closed.bs.alert .alert': function () {
        console.log('closed'); // does not trigger
    }
});
```

Oddly, `close.bs.alert` does work:

```
Template.alert.events({
    'close.bs.alert .alert': function () {
        console.log('closed'); // triggers
    }
});
```

Also, if I add the event via jQuery, I can capture `closed.bs.alert`:

```
$('.alert').on('closed.bs.alert', function () { 
   console.log('closed'); // triggers
});
```

So, I know I have my events formatted correctly and I know the `closed.bs.alert` event is triggering... but for some reason I can't catch it with Template.alert.events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dove in to the Bootstrap code and found where it triggered this event: [alert.js, line 50](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/alert.js#L50)

First, the technique that I got to work:

```
Templates.alert.onRendered({
    $('.alert').on('closed.bs.alert', function (e) {
        console.log('closed'); // triggers =D
    });
});
```

I think the problem lies in the fact that Bootstrap detaches the alert before triggering the event, so things like `$(document).on('closed.bs.alert', '.alert')` can't work. I don't know 100% for sure, but I suspect Meteor's `Template.my_template.events()` trigger using a very similar method as well.

Normally this would work:

```
$(function () {
    $('.alert').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
        console.log('closed'); // doesn't trigger
    });
});
```

However, Meteor throws a wrench in to that plan because I'm loading the alerts from data, they aren't there when that would trigger.

However, by putting a jQuery-style `on()` in a `Template.my_template.onRender()` seems to do the trick.

Also, Bootstrap doesn't throw the event unless the alert has the "fade" class. You can assign the fade class without including the "transition" module. If you leave it off, you just won't get the effect, but the event can fire regardless.

Comment: That's what I tried also, but it doesn't work for me. Anything else I need to watch out for? I got the fade class, and I put the event handler in the onRendered. I use the official twbs:bootstrap package instead of nemo64's, but I verified the javascript for alert handling is loaded.

Comment: I just recreated the same issue with nemo64:bootstrap, I can capture the close.bs.alert event, but not closed.bs.alert, so I'm assuming the problem is that the dom element is already removed when the event is fired.

Comment: @illuminaut Make sure you have added the "fade" class to the element. If it isn't present, the `closed.bs.alert` class is never fired. (See line 53 of the file I linked). If that isn't it, I'd recommend opening up a new question so you can post your code sample.